# What is the purpose of the [follow-up] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [follow-up](/questions/tagged/follow-up) tag seems to have no clear usage. It is being used for:

- Following users
- Follow-up questions that are based on previous questions
- Favoriting questions
- Receiving notifications when questions have new activity

I would say this should either be burninated or someone should define the tag better so that it can be cleaned up.

Comment: It's purpose is to die a heat death, in my opinion..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the humor :)